# How Do I Iterate Over Collections Inside a Dask Task Graph

Tags: dask

I have the following task graph.

```
def getdocs():
    return [doc1,doc2]

def tosents(doc):
    return doc.split(".")  # Except doc is a list of docs

def towords(sent):
    return sent.split(" ")  

graph = {
    "documents": (getdocs,),
    "sentences": (tosents,"documents"),
    "words": (towords, "sentences")
}
```

Each task returns a list, but I want those results to be parallelized to the receiving function, which should only take a single value (e.g. a string). Currently, the results are being passed along.

How can I indicate the results are to be enumerated over the receiving function? Using yield?

Thank you in advanced.

Answer (score 0):

It is unusual for people to construct their own Dask graphs, since the `delayed` interface is so easy to use. Where you have a function which returns a known number of outputs which you mean to treat separately (i.e., operate on in parallel), you can do something like

```
ddocs = delayed(getdocs, nout=2)
sentences = [delayed(tosentences)(doc) for doc in ddocs()]
```

where `tosentences` takes one doc as input. Each element of `sentences` will be a delayed object with a graph of its own. You can compute them in parallel if you pass them together to `compute()`.

-edit-

`ddocs` needed to be called; you can't iterate the delayed function, but you can iterate the delayed objects it makes.

Comment: Thanks. Yeah, I'm trying to see if I can use a nearly declarative way to construct task graphs. Doing it programmatically, while easy to program, has its downsides to declarative approach.

So in your example, can I still visualize "sentences" and get the full task graph at that point? It does it get collapsed as a single thing. I'm wanting to construct task graphs and visualize them in a data driven approach, ultimately.

Comment: I tried your example, but it does not work.


TypeError: Delayed objects of unspecified length are not iterable